# How can I insert following JSON in MongoDB collection as different documents

Tags: json, mongodb

I need to insert data in mongo but the JSON I am getting has multiple values in every field and I don't know how can I split them to insert in different documents.

I want to insert array data in different objects in MongoDB

```
{
  "activity_template_id": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    7
  ],
  "done_date": [
    "2019-08-10",
    "2019-08-10",
    "2019-08-10",
    "0000-01-01",
    "0000-01-01",
    "0000-01-01"
  ],
  "is_prescribed": [
    "N",
    "N",
    "N",
    "N",
    "N",
    "Y"
  ],
  "material_id": [
    1,
    5,
    21,
    10,
    14,
    0
  ],
  "qty": [
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0"
  ],
  "unit_id": [
    1,
    1,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],

}
```

Comment: what language do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As far as I know) there is no feature in MongoDB itself that would process input data like that. You would do that in application code before calling MongoDB.

If there is no separate application, you can use standard JavaScript functions within the `mongo` shell to do that.